# how to convert local time into UTC time in liquid language

Tags: twilio, liquid

i have a time format like below which results local time,

```
 {{ "now" | date: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" }}
```

but i want to use UTC time, how can i do that...

Comment: I'm guessing you need this as part of some sort of Twilio flow and that's why you've added the twilio tag. Perhaps you can expand a bit on how you are using Twilio and how this fits in?

Answer (score -2):

If you first convert to the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC, and then format your date, it should result in the time in UTC:

```
{{ "now" | date: "%s" | date: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" }}
```

Comment: This is not working. It is resulting in %s